# Indentation removed after replacing text within a bulleted list in Google Docs using Google Docs API

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api

When we use Docs API to replace text within a bulleted list, the list structure is disturbed so that the last bulleted item has the bullet and indentation removed.
(See before and after images)

[image: Before Image]

[image: After :Icon got removed after replacing text]

Library Method to replace text : **Class Google_Service_Docs_ReplaceAllTextRequest**

Library Link : https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/docs/v1/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Docs_ReplaceAllTextRequest.html

Piece of Code in PHP:

```
$taskText = "Hello World";    
$requests[] = new Google_Service_Docs_Request(array(
                        'replaceAllText' => array(
                            'containsText' => array(
                                'text' => $taskText,
                                'matchCase' => 'true'
                            ),
                            'replaceText' => '(Done) '.$taskText
                        )
                    ));
```

> Note that if the bulleted list contains only one item, that item has the bullet and indentation removed, but when there are multiple items (as shown), only the last bullet is removed.

Comment: Could you please provide the code related to `$taskText`?

Comment: @Iamblichus I have updated the code in post. `$taskText` is having text which I am trying to replace in Google Doc.

Comment: I tried to reproduce this but I successfully replaced text from a list without removing any bullets. Could you please clarify how were the bullets added, just in case this might be important in causing the outcome you are getting?

Comment: @Iamblichus I am adding bullets manually from the toolbar of Google Docs. Here is the screenshot link -  (https://ibb.co/L8j95KR)

Comment: Your code replaces `Hello World` through `Done`, but in the screenshot you provided `Hello world` is still present. Are you sure that the screenshot is the result after replacing (rather than adding `Done` in any other way)? If so, please provide a test document that would reproduce this issue.

Comment: I want to replace `Hello World` through `(Done) Hello World` . In the code `'replaceText' => '(Done) '.$taskText` , `$taskText` contains the string `Hello World`. 
I am sharing the link of the Google Doc where you can try this scenario by following the below steps :

1. Remove all the `(Done)` from the Google Doc, if exists.
2. Add `#facil` on bottom of the document in a new line
3. Now leave the document for 2 mins and reload it.

Here is the link :

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1iUirQbS5TH3ve8W6yUfcgarV2HdRG_8IB9INis4C6rA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @ziganotschka
I want to add one more thing here .. 
I want to use "replace method" because I don't have an index of `$taskText` as I am 
 locating it based on bullet.

Comment: So far I could not reproduce it. What do you mean by `#facil`?  Can you please test with the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate) with the request body `{
  "requests": [
    {
      "replaceAllText": {
        "containsText": {
          "text": "Hello World",
          "matchCase": true
        },
        "replaceText": "(Done) Hello World"
      }
    }
  ]
}` and tell me if this gives you the same issue?

Comment: @ziganotschka 
Thank you for help !! Issue has been fixed now ..